# with and pmin from R to Python

Tags: python, r

I have troubles when writing small part of R code into Python.
Here is the R code:

```
W <- expand.grid(list(A = 1:10, C = 1:15))
W$B <- 40 - rowSums(W)

GC <- with(
  W,
  pmin(floor(53*C - 0.9*C^2), pmin(floor(52*B - 1.1*B^2), pmin(62*A, 614)))
)
```

I need it to rewrite it into Python. This is what I have until now:

```py
import pandas as pd
import itertools


d =  {'A': range(1, 11), 'C': range(1, 16)}

df = pd.DataFrame(itertools.product(*d.values()),columns=d.keys())
df["B"] = 40 - df["A"] - df["C"]
```

But what is the most pythonic way how to write `with` function into Python? That is this part:

```
GC <- with(
  W,
  pmin(floor(53*C - 0.9*C^2), pmin(floor(52*B - 1.1*B^2), pmin(62*A, 614)))
)
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you summarize what `with` does in R?

Comment: looks like [`assign`/`eval` is what you want](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_r.html#with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent would be [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```py
df.assign(B=40 - df['A'] - df['C'])
```

If you want to have a reference relative to the object itself, use a callable:

```py
df.assign(B=lambda d: 40 - d['A'] - d['C'])
```

If you want to use a name with special characters or spaces:

```py
df.assign(**{'B': lambda d: 40 - d['A'] - d['C'])})
```

##### alternative

you can use [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html)

```py
df.eval('B = 40-A-C')
```

##### minimum of several functions:

```
df['Gc'] = pd.concat([df.eval('53*C - 0.9*C**2'),
                      df.eval('52*B - 1.1*B**2'),
                      df.eval('62*A').clip(upper=614)],
                     axis=1).min(axis=1)
```

output:

```
      A   C   B     Gc
0     1   1  38   52.1
1     1   2  37   62.0
2     1   3  36   62.0
3     1   4  35   62.0
4     1   5  34   62.0
..   ..  ..  ..    ...
145  10  11  19  474.1
146  10  12  18  506.4
147  10  13  17  536.9
148  10  14  16  550.4
149  10  15  15  532.5

[150 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: I was asking about the equivalent of the with function that is `GC <- with(
  W,
  pmin(floor(53*C - 0.9*C^2), pmin(floor(52*B - 1.1*B^2), pmin(62*A, 614)))
)`

Comment: @vojtam maybe give more details on what the function does **and the expected logic** independently of the R code

Comment: it should find the minimum among three function and insert it as a new column. I tried simple `df.assign(Gc=min(53*df["C"] - 0.9*df["C"]^2, 27))`, but it returns `TypeError: Cannot perform 'xor' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]`

Comment: @vojtam OK, I'm not certain of the exact R logic, but assuming you want the minimum of several outputs of functions, you can `concat` and `min` see update